# How can I display a different image according the link clicked inside a php file?

Tags: php, html, css

I have a few php files, lets call them planet1.php, planet2.php, planet3.php and satellite.php.

Each "planet" has a link to this unique "satellite.php" file this is because the information there is all the same no matter the "planet" where its being redirected. Now as I say all infomartion is the same but an image -which is inside a DIV as a background-image-.

**Here's my question**

How can I click the link in planet1.php and open satellite.php with  visible or click on planet2.php and open satellite.php with ?

I have three differents "planets" and I need to display only one  acoording where it's being redirected.

Thanks!

This is how I solved it (with the help of Lev Buchel)

Inside -> satellite.php

```
if (<? echo $_GET["planet"] ?> == 1){
    document.getElementById("planet").classList.add("planet1");
}else if (<? echo $_GET["planet"] ?> == 2) {
    document.getElementById("planet").classList.add("planet2");
}else{
    document.getElementById("planet").classList.add("planet3");
}
```

Inside every planetX.php file

Styles...

```
<style>
    .planet1{background-image: url('img1.JPG');}
    .planet2{background-image: url('img2.JPG');}
    .planet3{background-image: url('img3.JPG');}
</style>
```

Actual div with the image...

Comment: In the link (href) you can pass a query parameter e.g. `?planet=a`. Now, in your common satellite.php file, you can echo the background-image dynamically based on this query parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understood you correctly, you want the same "satellite" page to display a different image according to which "planet" file was clicked to reach it.
What you can do is to use a "GET" method, for example in your planet1.php file the href will look like this :

```
href="satellite.php/?planet=1"
```

Same goes for planet2 (planet=2) and planet3 (planet=3).

In your satellite.php page you can check which planet the user came from using

```
if ($_GET["planet"] == 1)
    document.getElementById("yourDiv").classList.add("planet1");
```

Now you can set a different background for class planet1/2/3.